# Send XML file over socket C++

Tags: c++, xml, winsock2

I'm trying to send a `.ui` file's content by

```
std::ifstream f;
f.open(filePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
int fileSize = f.tellg();
char *bytes = new char[fileSize];

f.read((char *) bytes, fileSize);

send(clientSocket, std::to_string(fileSize).c_str(), 16, 0);
send(clientSocket, bytes, fileSize, 0);
f.close();
delete [] bytes;
```

Despite being opened and size of file is counted correctly, on debug, I see

```
f.read((char *) bytes, fileSize); f: std::ifstream fileSize:2328 bytes: 0x6824b0 "\r\360\255\272 ...
```

The sequence

> \r\360\255\272

repeats further and eventually ends with

> \r\360\255\272\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\356\376\356\376\356\376", <incomplete sequence \356\376>

How to correctly pass and receive any xml content over `WinSock2_32`?

Comment: Assuming as you have that absolutely nothing went wrong in opening the file and reaping the size, what justifies your further assumption the file size as string is precisely 16 characters long? Especially when clearly you show a value that would only occupy 4 characters? Just curious. Regardless, your read is blindly failing because you're already at the end of the file. That's what `std::ios::ate` does (and in fact you rely on that to reap the size). You never rewound the file, and therefore your read actually reads nothing, you never check for any error, and march on.

Comment: You can't close a serial stream until the data is received on the far end.  Recommend you send an response from other end to verify the data was received before closing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeking the file stream back to position 0 before reading the bytes, so `f.read()` will fail. Add a call to `f.seekg(0)` beforehand.

Also, you should send the `fileSize` in binary format, not as a string, especially since the string is NOT 16 bytes in length.

Try this:

```cpp
std::ifstream f(filePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
if (!f.is_open()) ...

int fileSize = f.tellg();
if (fileSize < 0) ...

char *bytes = new char[fileSize];
f.seekg(0);
f.read(bytes, fileSize);

int32_t tmp = htonl(fileSize);
send(clientSocket, &tmp, sizeof(tmp), 0);
send(clientSocket, bytes, fileSize, 0);

delete [] bytes;
f.close();
```

If you absolutely need to send the `fileSize` as a 16-character string, use a formatted `char[]` buffer for that, eg:

```cpp
std::ifstream f(filePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
if (!f.is_open()) ...

int fileSize = f.tellg();
if (fileSize < 0) ...

char *bytes = new char[fileSize];
f.seekg(0);
f.read(bytes, fileSize);

char s_fileSize[17] = {};
sprintf(s_fileSize, "%0.16d", fileSize);

send(clientSocket, s_fileSize, 16, 0);
send(clientSocket, bytes, fileSize, 0);

delete [] bytes;
f.close();
```